# Extract child key and flatten into parent object output in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to simplify a nested JSON structure using JQ

#### Input

```json
[
  {
    "defaultBranchRef": {
      "name": "main"
    },
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/stack-posts"
  },
  {
    "defaultBranchRef": {
      "name": "master"
    },
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/HelloSERN"
  }
]
```

#### Desired Output

```json
[
  {
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/stack-posts",
    "defaultBranchName": "main"
  },
  {
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/HelloSERN",
    "defaultBranchName": "master"
  }
]
```

#### Attempted Solution

I can retrieve each of the individual fields at any depth

- [Get `nameWithOwner`](https://jqplay.org/s/6H2F1AkdAO)

  ```js
  [.[]|.nameWithOwner] // ["KyleMit/stack-posts","KyleMit/HelloSERN"]
  ```
- [Get `defaultBranchRef.name`](https://jqplay.org/s/ySBjK4KpsY)

  ```js
  [.[]|.defaultBranchRef.name] // ["main","master"]
  ```

But can't quite get how to combine fields / selectors to return mulitple values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update `|=` the `defaultBranchRef` field to the content of its `name` subfield:

```sh
jq '.[].defaultBranchRef |= .name'
```

```json
[
  {
    "defaultBranchRef": "main",
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/stack-posts"
  },
  {
    "defaultBranchRef": "master",
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/HelloSERN"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YgodN5agGI)

Answer (score 1):

Open to other solutions, but one way to combine is to use [**Object Construction**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D) like

```js
[.[]|{nameWithOwner, defaultBranchName: .defaultBranchRef.name}]
```

Which [results in the following output](https://jqplay.org/s/-6FNUDE2rj):

```
  {
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/stack-posts",
    "defaultBranchName": "main"
  },
  {
    "nameWithOwner": "KyleMit/HelloSERN",
    "defaultBranchName": "master"
  }
]
```

Comment: That is exactly how I would have done it.